# Joining table and map displays

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have an index method:

```
def index
    if params[:city] || params[:lab_type]
        @labs = Lab.in_city(params[:city]).with_type(params[:lab_type]).advanced_search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    else
        @labs = Lab.advanced_search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    end
    # Marker setup:
    if @places.count > 1
        @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@labs.select(:name, :latitude, :longitude)) do |lab, marker|
            marker.lat lab.latitude
            marker.lng lab.longitude
        end
    end
    # Only labs with offer_items.count > 1 if filled_params 
    @labs = @labs.joins( :offer_items ).group( 'labs.id' ).having( 'count( lab_id ) > 1' ) if params[:filled_only]
end
```

With code like this I can use "filled_only" and it produces result as expected - giving me only labs that have any offer count more than 0;

However if I place the code with `joins, group, having` before the `Marker setup` and set `filled_only` to `true` I get an error from my database saying:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ... BY labs.id HAVING (count( lab_id ) > 1) ORDER BY id asc
```

What might be causing this? Does the code from `Marker setup` change anything in my `@places` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Error is indicating that you have selected at least two columns name `id`.

`ORDER BY id asc`

looks like you have order by and query can not decide which table column name id will be used.

Change `ORDER BY id asc` by `ORDER BY your_table_name.id asc` where `your_table_name` is the name of your table by which table id you want to sort.

Seems like `sort_column` should be changed.

Comment: I got the table_name from `lab_instance.class.table_name` and added it to the method called `sort_column` which is: `Lab.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "labs.id"` and what I get is `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Hash)`

Comment: I see the problem. After all the joins etc. methods when calling `@labs.count` it returns a hash istead of a number